# parse data from a website (.xml)

Tags: python, xml, parsing, xml-parsing

I trying to parse data from a website, and i can do the following:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from urllib import urlopen

link = urlopen('http://www.yr.no/place/Norway/Sør-Trøndelag/Trondheim/Trondheim/varsel.xml')
tree = ET.parse(link)
root = tree.getroot()

data = root.findall('meta')
for metar in data:
    print metar.find('lastupdate').text
```

This is an example of something that works. But I need to parse the temp value, and the `windspeed` name `ect`. How can I do that?

Comment: What programming language did you want to do this with?

Comment: While there are so few lines - it's python :) (edited tags)

Comment: programming language: Python

Comment: you can use Xpath and this is a will be like a yourdoc.xpath('//windspeed/text()') http://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html

Answer (score 1):

This is a job for `xpath`:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from urllib import urlopen

link = urlopen('http://www.yr.no/place/Norway/Sør-Trøndelag/Trondheim/Trondheim/varsel.xml')
tree = ET.parse(link)
root = tree.getroot()

data = root.findall('.//windSpeed')
results = [item.attrib for item in data]
print results
```

prints:

```
[{'mps': '2.4', 'name': 'Light breeze'},
 {'mps': '2.4', 'name': 'Light breeze'},
 {'mps': '1.9', 'name': 'Light breeze'},
 {'mps': '0.5', 'name': 'Light air'},
 {'mps': '3.6', 'name': 'Gentle breeze'},
...
```

Comment: Just one more question if you have the time.... How can i get, say line 3, stored? Whan I set "a=" insted of print I just get the first line....

Comment: Sure, I've edited the answer: collecting results into list. Is that what you want?